# saving data using session after page reload in cakephp

Tags: session, cakephp

My scenario is I need to save the user entered data on the same. What I need to do and what are the files I need to work on?

```
<div>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_cust_name',
                            array('label' => __l('Customer Name')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_cust_address',
                            array('label' => __l('Customer Address')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_cust_city',
                            array('label' => __l('Customer City')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_cust_country',
                            array('label' => __l('Customer Country')));
?>
</div>
<div class="grid_11 grid_right">
<?php
    //echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_cust_country',
    //                        array('label' => __l('Customer Country'),
    //                              'type' => 'select',
    //                              'options' => $gateway_options['countries'],
    //                              'empty' => __l('Please Select')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_cust_state', 
                            array('label' => __l('Customer State')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_zip', 
                            array('label' => __l('Zip Code')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_cust_tel', 
                            array('label' => __l('Phone')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Deal.billing_cust_email', 
                            array('label' => __l('Email')));
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What for do you need to save the data in session? Toreneder filled form so user could fix mistakes if form will not validate?

Comment: You created a form for user to enter data. So why on earth do you want to save data on page load? Just put a submit button in your form and submit the form to your controller. Default form submission will reload your page.

Comment: @Michel will reload if he wont make `$this->redirect()` before =)

Comment: @Bulkin that was why I said "default form submission". If you do not do anything else. :)

Comment: having two pages page A and page B , Page A have one form there user will enter the details in Page A Form then they will click and navigate to Page B by clicking the link not a Submit button that time page A got reloaded then it moves page B , Here Page B also have the same form which is reside in Page A , But page A get reloaded so the form get empty this cause forced users enter the same details which is they did entered in Page A already it was embarrassing moment .